# Playing Audio file freezing UI using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In this particular application I am showing Video using Web Cam.
When I press any button it runs `Audio file` using `SoundPlayer`.

**Code to Run Audio**

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Audio\audio1.wav");
player.PlayLooping();
```

> This code snippet freezing the UI even if I put this code in thread
> still my UI is freezing

So can anyone please tell me how I can solve this problem. Thank you

**Edit1:**

So in above code snippet
I am declaring Sound Player object Globally

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Audio\audio1.wav");
```

and calling function `PlayAudio()` on Button click Event

```
private void PlayAudio()
{
    player.PlayLooping();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method ?  Is it inside the xaml.cs file or you have implemented MVVM and this code is from your view model ?  I think this code is running on UI thread that's why your UI is freezing.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Sir, I am calling this method from xaml.cs file

Comment: @Lakshraj it should not block.. can you please add the calling code and the Xaml fragment that activates that code ?

Answer (score 0):

It should NOT freeze the UI, unless there is some other blocking code running. Below is a sample 'Hello World' WPF code with your code sample -

XAML -

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Play" Height="50" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Test" Height="50" Width="100" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtSample" Text="Hello"/>
</StackPanel>
```

xaml.cs -

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Audio\audio1.wav");
    player.PlayLooping();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtSample.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Now click on the `Play` button to play the sound, now while the sound is playing click on `Test` button any number of times it should not freeze.

Also as per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.8) `PlayLooping` should not hang UI as it runs in a new thread by default.

[image]